# Bias grad in linear regression remains small compared to weight grad, and intercept is not properly learnt

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have thrown together a dummy model to showcase linear regression in pytorch, but I find that my model is not properly learning. It's doing well when it comes to learning the slope, but the intercept is not really budging. Printing out the grads at every epoch tells me that, indeed, the grad is a lot smaller for the bias. Why is that? How can I remedy it, so the intercept is properly learnt?

This is what happens (a set to 0 to illustrate):

[image]

```
# Create some dummy data: we establish a linear relationship between x and y
a = np.random.rand()
b = np.random.rand()

a=0

x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=100, num=100)
y = a * x + b

# Now let's create some noisy measurements
noise = np.random.normal(size=100)
y_noisy = a * x + b + noise

# What's the overall error?
mse_actual = np.sum(np.power(y-y_noisy,2))/len(y)

# Visualize
plt.scatter(x,y_noisy, label='Measurements', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(x,y,'r', label='Underlying')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Let's learn something!
inputs = torch.from_numpy(x).type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(1)
targets = torch.from_numpy(y_noisy).type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(1)


# This is our model (one hidden node + bias)
model = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=1e-5)
loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()

# What does it predict right now?
shuffled_inputs, preds = [], []
for input, target in zip(inputs,targets):

    pred = model(input)
    shuffled_inputs.append(input.detach().numpy()[0])
    preds.append(pred.detach().numpy()[0])

# Visualize
plt.scatter(x,y_noisy, color='blue', label='Measurements', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(shuffled_inputs, preds, color='orange', label='Predictions', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(x,y,'r', label='Underlying')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Let's train!
epochs = 100
a_s, b_s = [], []

for epoch in range(epochs):

    # Reset optimizer values
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Predict values using current model
    preds = model(inputs)

    # How far off are we?
    loss = loss_function(targets,preds)

    # Calculate the gradient
    loss.backward()

    # Update model
    optimizer.step()

    for p in model.parameters():
        print('Grads:', p.grad)

    # New parameters
    a_s.append(list(model.parameters())[0].item())
    b_s.append(list(model.parameters())[1].item())

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} -- loss = {loss}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a non-answer, but just use more epochs or add more datapoints. When you have 100 datapoints with noise as significant as you had (if you just plot the initial data it becomes obvious) the model will struggle with MSE as a loss.

I can't see your image (work blocked imgur...) but I found it looked bad if you didn't adjust the axes on your matplotlib plot because it was so zoomed in on the x axis (when a=0), so I zoomed out of that too:

```
# Create some dummy data: we establish a linear relationship between x and y
a = np.random.rand()
b = np.random.rand()

a=0
N = 10000
x = np.linspace(start=0, stop=100, num=N)
y = a * x + b

# Now let's create some noisy measurements
noise = np.random.normal(size=N)*0.1
y_noisy = a * x + b + noise

# What's the overall error?
mse_actual = np.sum(np.power(y-y_noisy,2))/len(y)

# Visualize
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y_noisy, label='Measurements', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(x,y,'r', label='Underlying')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Let's learn something!
inputs = torch.from_numpy(x).type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(1)
targets = torch.from_numpy(y_noisy).type(torch.FloatTensor).unsqueeze(1)

# This is our model (one hidden node + bias)
model = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=1e-5)
loss_function = torch.nn.MSELoss()

# Let's train!
epochs = 50000
a_s, b_s = [], []

for epoch in range(epochs):

    # Reset optimizer values
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # Predict values using current model
    preds = model(inputs)

    # How far off are we?
    loss = loss_function(targets,preds)

    # Calculate the gradient
    loss.backward()

    # Update model
    optimizer.step()

    #for p in model.parameters():
    #    print('Grads:', p.grad)

    # New parameters
    a_s.append(list(model.parameters())[0].item())
    b_s.append(list(model.parameters())[1].item())

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} -- loss = {loss}")


# What does it predict right now?
shuffled_inputs, preds = [], []
for input, target in zip(inputs,targets):

    pred = model(input)
    shuffled_inputs.append(input.detach().numpy()[0])
    preds.append(pred.detach().numpy()[0])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y_noisy, color='blue', label='Measurements', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(shuffled_inputs, preds, color='orange', label='Predictions', alpha=.7)
plt.plot(x,y,'r', label='Underlying')
plt.axis([0,100,y.min()-1,y.max()+1])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: predictions]

Comment: Yeah, the code may have varied slightly from what I used to create the plot. But adding more epochs solved the issue. The model learns the slope (w) far more quickly than the intercept (bias). Giving it enough time/epochs allows it to get there, eventually. Another tip I got was to use an adaptive optimizer (e.g. Adam), because it adapts the learning rate per parameter. Thanks for responding!

Comment: Glad to help, could you please accept the answer?